# How to set a specific duration to interpolate along a path one point at time?

Tags: d3.js, transition, interpolation

I'm trying to figure out the best way to interpolate a circle along a path as Mike Bostock does in this example: http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1705868. However, instead of setting one transition value as he does, I'd like to be able to set a unique duration for each point-to-point interpolation; e.g., transition the circle from node[0] to node [1] over x milliseconds, transition from node [1] to node [2] over y milliseconds, etc. Is there a way to do this without splitting the path up into a bunch of smaller separate paths and transitioning along them consecutively? The limiting factor seems to be path.getTotalLength() - is there a way to get the length of only the subset of a path?

```
transition();

function transition() {
   circle.transition()
   .duration(10000)
   .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
   .each("end", transition);
}

// Returns an attrTween for translating along the specified path element.
function translateAlong(path) {
   var l = path.getTotalLength();
   return function(d, i, a) {
      return function(t) {
      var p = path.getPointAtLength(t * l);
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")";
   };
};
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There's in a fact a way but it's way too ugly (because it needs an initial brute force computation), the solution involves the following:

First of all you need an array with the transition times between nodes, in my example is `times`, for example the first element `3000` corresponds to the time in ms to get from `[480,200]` to `[580,400]`

- compute the sum of the transition times (needed for the duration of the overall transition)
- compute the linear time in ms to reach each one of the points that made this path, this is actually tricky when the path between two points is not a line e.g. a curve, in my example I compute those times by brute force which makes it ugly, it'd be awesome if there was a method that computed the path length needed to get to some point lying on the path itself, unfortunately such a method doesn't exist as far as I know
- Finally once you know the linear times you have to compute the correct time as if it followed the list of the numbers in the `times` array e.g.

Let's say that the linear time to get to the first point is 50ms and we're currently on the time `t < 50ms`, we have to map this value which is between [0ms, 50ms] to somewhere in the range [0ms, 3000ms] which is given by the formula `3000 * (t ms - 0ms) / (50ms - 0ms)`

```js
var points = [
  [480, 200],
  [580, 400],
  [680, 100],
  [780, 300],
  [180, 300],
  [280, 100],
  [380, 400]
];

var times = [3000, 100, 5000, 100, 3000, 100, 1000]
var totalTime = times.reduce(function (a, b) {return a + b}, 0)

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr("width", 960)
    .attr("height", 500);

var path = svg.append("path")
    .data([points])
    .attr("d", d3.svg.line()
    .tension(0) // Catmull–Rom
    .interpolate("cardinal-closed"));

svg.selectAll(".point")
    .data(points)
  .enter().append("circle")
    .attr("r", 4)
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d + ")"; });

var circle = svg.append("circle")
    .attr("r", 13)
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + points[0] + ")");

function transition() {
  circle.transition()
      .duration(totalTime)
      .ease('linear')
      .attrTween("transform", translateAlong(path.node()))
      .each("end", transition);
}

// initial computation, linear time needed to reach a point
var timeToReachPoint = []
var pathLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
var pointIndex = 0
for (var t = 0; pointIndex < points.length && t <= 1; t += 0.0001) {
  var data = points[pointIndex]
  var point = path.node().getPointAtLength(t * pathLength)
  // if the distance to the point[i] is approximately less than 1 unit
  // make `t` the linear time needed to get to that point
  if (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(data[0] - point.x, 2) + Math.pow(data[1] - point.y, 2)) < 1) {
    timeToReachPoint.push(t);
    pointIndex += 1
  }
}
timeToReachPoint.push(1)

function translateAlong(path) {
  return function(d, i, a) {
    return function(t) {
      // TODO: optimize
      var timeElapsed = t * totalTime     
      var acc = 0
      for (var it = 0; acc + times[it] < timeElapsed; it += 1) {
        acc += times[it]
      }
      var previousTime = timeToReachPoint[it]
      var diffWithNext = timeToReachPoint[it + 1] - timeToReachPoint[it]
      // range mapping
      var placeInDiff = diffWithNext * ((timeElapsed - acc) / times[it])     
      var p = path.getPointAtLength((previousTime + placeInDiff) * pathLength)
      return "translate(" + p.x + "," + p.y + ")"
    }
  }
}

transition();
```

```css
path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}

circle {
  fill: steelblue;
  stroke: #fff;
  stroke-width: 3px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
```